# AWS CloudWatch alarm is in "insufficient data" state when metrics are pushed using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

Alarm is on insufficient state for long time.

Graph of the metric:

[image]

This is the code that creates the alarm:

```
import boto3

# Create CloudWatch client
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

# Create alarm
cloudwatch.put_metric_alarm(
    AlarmName='Web_Server_CPU_Utilization',
    ComparisonOperator='GreaterThanThreshold',
    EvaluationPeriods=1,
    MetricName='CPUUtilization',
    Namespace='AWS/EC2',
    Period=60,
    Statistic='Average',
    Threshold=70.0,
    ActionsEnabled=False,
    AlarmDescription='Alarm when server CPU exceeds 70%',
    Dimensions=[
        {
          'Name': 'InstanceId',
          'Value': 'INSTANCE_ID'
        },
    ],
    Unit='Seconds'
)
```

Also tried to create a metric alarm for Custom metrics, but this has different issue.

All the pre-defined metrics are in `AWS namespaces` and custom metrics are in `Custom namespaces`.

Tried giving `Namespace='Custom/EC2'`, `Namespace='EC2'`, `Namespace='Custom/EC2'`,`Namespace='AWS/EC2'`,`Namespace='Custom/Custom'`.

But any of those cases. It is not pushing to the respected metric.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have [detailed monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch-new.html#enable-detailed-monitoring) enabled in the EC2 instance?

> By default, your instance is enabled for basic monitoring. You can
>   optionally enable detailed monitoring. After you enable detailed
>   monitoring, the Amazon EC2 console displays monitoring graphs with a 1-minute period for the instance.

You're configuring the alarm on a 60s period and alarming on 1 datapoint so if the metric is not published every minute [the alarm will go into insufficient data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html#alarm-evaluation). You can enable detailed monitoring in your EC2 instances or change the alarm period to 300 seconds.

Comment: What did you try exactly? :) Enabling detailed monitoring or increasing the alarm period? My answer should fix your first question (Alarm on insufficient data).

Answer (score 1):

Try to send `put_metric_alarm` request without `Unit` property. The thing is that if you create an alarm based on metrics, you shouldn't have dimension or unit properties defined.

Answer (score 0):

How are you pushing custom metrics ? Are you using your own script or one of the CloudWatch Agent ?

If CloudWatch Agent - then check the Agent's logs.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/troubleshooting-CloudWatch-Agent.html#CloudWatch-Agent-troubleshooting-loginfo

If using some sdk (like boto3) print the response or add debug
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/boto3.html

I tried with the AWS cli-

- **Error**

`saws> aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace AWS/EC2  --metric-name Sufyan --value 32 --region ap-southeast-2`

`An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the PutMetricData operation: The value AWS/ for parameter Namespace is invalid.`

- Worked fine

`saws> aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace Custom/EC2  --metric-name Test --value 32 --region ap-southeast-2`

Comment: I am using my custom script to push metrics,  using this to push data  `aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name python_process_status --dimensions Instance='instanceid'  --namespace "Custom" --value 100`

Comment: It is still on insufficient data for pre-defined metrics and not catching the metrics of the custom one's

Comment: I tried the cil you pasted and it worked for me and I can see the custom metric on the CloudWatch metric console (can also use the cli get-metric-statistics).

you can also run - aws configure - and keep hitting the enter key to confirm the region configured (default is us-east-1).

When you say InsufficientData are you checking some Alarm ? Make sure the Alarm is referring to the correct metrics' Namespace, MericName and Dimension/s.

Comment: it is not about the custom metrics, It is about the alarm for custom metrics through boto3

Comment: Or you can provide me the aws cli command for put metric alaram it would be helpful

Comment: you can check the first pic in Question, it is Giving insufficient data.